# IEnumerable<string> System.ObjectDisposedException

Tags: c#

On some machines but not on others I get `System.ObjectDisposedException` using this class.

```
class LogComparer
    {
        private string firstFile;
        private string secondFile;
        private IEnumerable<string> inFirstNotInSecond;
        private IEnumerable<string> inSecondNotInFirst;

        public LogComparer(string firstFile, string secondFile)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(firstFile) || !File.Exists(secondFile))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Input file location is not valid.");
            }
            this.firstFile = firstFile;
            this.secondFile = secondFile;
            GenerateDiff();
        }

        public string FirstFile
        {
            get
            {
                return firstFile;
            }
        }

        public bool IsEqual
        {
            get
            {
                return inFirstNotInSecond.SequenceEqual(inSecondNotInFirst);
            }
        }

        public string SecondFile
        {
            get
            {
                return secondFile;
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<string> InFirstNotInSecond
        {
            get
            {
                return inFirstNotInSecond;
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<string> InSecondNotInFirst
        {
            get
            {
                return inSecondNotInFirst;
            }
        }

        private void GenerateDiff()
        {
            var file1Lines = File.ReadLines(firstFile);
            var file2Lines = File.ReadLines(secondFile);

            inFirstNotInSecond = file1Lines.Except(file2Lines);
            inSecondNotInFirst = file2Lines.Except(file1Lines);
        }
    }
```

> ```
> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot read from a closed TextReader.
> ObjectName: 
>    at System.IO.__Error.ReaderClosed()
>    at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadLine()
>    at System.IO.File.<InternalReadLines>d__0.MoveNext()
>    at System.Linq.Enumerable.<ExceptIterator>d__99`1.MoveNext()
>    at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
> ```

After modifying `GenerateDiff()` to:

```
private void GenerateDiff()
{
    var file1Lines = File.ReadLines(firstFile).ToList();
    var file2Lines = File.ReadLines(secondFile).ToList();

    inFirstNotInSecond = file1Lines.Except(file2Lines);
    inSecondNotInFirst = file2Lines.Except(file1Lines);
}
```

I can't reproduce the exception.

Interesting thing is that this is not working:

```
private void GenerateDiff()
{
    var file1Lines = File.ReadLines(firstFile);
    var file2Lines = File.ReadLines(secondFile);

    inFirstNotInSecond = file1Lines.Except(file2Lines).ToList();
    inSecondNotInFirst = file2Lines.Except(file1Lines).ToList();
}
```

I'm using an instance of this class `diff` here for example. No `using` or `Dispose` anywhere. No tasks or threads.

```
if (diff.InSecondNotInFirst.Any(s => !s.Contains("bxsr")))
```

Could someone please explain the root cause? Thank you.

(Our guess is that this is because of `IEnumerable<>` implements lazy loading and the garbage collector closes the reader before I want to access `InFirstNotInSecond` or `InSecondNotInFirst`. But using `GC.Collect()` there are still no exception on some machines.)

Comment: I am really doubtful this is the code giving the exception. In your call stack for example there is `Any()`, which you don't use in your code. Can you show the full code you are actually running? You happen to have `using` or `Dispose` statements anywhere? Any tasks or threads?

Comment: @PatrickHofman if you take a closer look at the stacktrace, you'll see a 'ExceptIterator' in the second line from the bottom. Which leads me to believe that the 'Except' method of Linq, internally, calls Any.

Comment: I'm using an instance of this class `diff` here for example. No `using` or `Dispose` anywhere. No tasks or threads.

    `if (diff.InSecondNotInFirst.Any(s => !s.Contains("bxsr")))`

Comment: @SteffenWinkler No, it is the calling code obviously. But that is missing from the question. > not any more...

Comment: Yeah sorry.. Added my comment to the question too.

Comment: Reading file content either way should work. But the second snippet will try to execute `Except()` over 2 opened streams. First time (where you assigne result to `inFirstNotInSecond`) it will work, but second time (`inSecondNotInFirst`) won't (for whatever reasons, perhaps internal implementation closes underlying stream, so following up `GetEnumerator` returns closed stream and you get your exception). You can either materialize results (as you already do with `ToList()`), but that is memory expensive or you can open file again (call `File.ReadLines()` again),which is slightly less performant

Comment: @bencemeszaros `ReadLines` is used when you want to process a stream of lines instead of loading everything in memory and avoid loading eg large log files in memory. Your class is written as if everything is in memory. What do you want to do? If you want to process large files, you'll have to change your code to actually work in a pull fashion. If not, then you should load everything at once with `ReadAllLines`. BTW, `Except` can't work unless everything is already in memory

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, *"everything is already in memory"* - are you sure? What does "deferred execution" means for it on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx) page?

Comment: @Sinatr I wrote `as if everything is in memory`. When using the pull or streaming model, you don't close your source because you are going to need it. You don't cache intermediate IEnumerables either, to avoid executing the same query twice. This class though caches the resulting IEnumerables, not the results, and discards the source. The same error would be thrown if the class loaded data from a database and closed the connection

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I am not asking about OP implementation, but regarding `Except` (as I recommended more memory efficient solution than `ReadAllLines` or OP's with two `ToList()` ones). Can you comment on it if my assumption is wrong please?

Comment: @Sinatr you mean about Except? [Yes it is](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L785). You can't check that the data on the first IEnumerable exists or not if you don't load the entire second IEnumerable.

Comment: @Sinatr To avoid loading one or the other input, you'd need to sort both inputs and perform the equivalent of a merge join - walk both sorted sequences checking for inequality

Comment: @bencemeszaros which .net framework are you working on?

Comment: @OfirWinegarten C# 4.0. Thank you guys, very insightful comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,1049) we see that `File.ReadLines` returns a `ReadLinesIterator`.

And [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/ReadLinesIterator.cs,25) you can see they Dispose after enumeration.

That means that the enumeration with `File.ReadLines` can happen only once.
It's better to use `File.ReadAllLines` which will enumerate first and return a concrete array.

Comment: That's the same as any other IEnumerable - subsequent iterations mean that the query/processing that produced them has to run *again*. `ReadLines` uses the same pull model that IEnumerable uses - data is *pulled* from the source as needed.  The OP's code though doesn't work like that - the original IEnumerable is discarded and another one cached, even though its source is gone

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos After examining the source code again, you are most definitely right. However, examining the exception again I noticed `InternalReadLines` which is I think the  previous buggy [implementation](http://dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/IO/File@cs/1305376/File@cs)  of it.

Comment: @OfirWinegarten It can be, it is C# 4.0

Answer (score 1):

With the immediate call to `ToList()` you force `ReadLines` to execute immediately and read the entire file. Going on, you now are dealing with a `List<string>` and not an `IENumerable` anymore.

The reason the second method doesn't work is, that you are, again, creating two `IENumerables` that are only (and at the same time repeatedly) evaluated when the `Except` methods are called. The `ToList()` behind the `Except` just converts the `IENumerable` you get from the `Except` method to a `List<string>`.

As to why you get a `ObjectDisposedException` I guess that the `TextReader` will be disposed after being enumerated and since you are trying to go through the same `IENumeration`s twice a `ToList()` won't help if it's placed at the end of the `Except`s

Answer (score 1):

This may require a lot of memory as *both* files will be loaded:

```
private void GenerateDiff()
{
    var file1Lines = File.ReadLines(firstFile).ToList();
    var file2Lines = File.ReadLines(secondFile).ToList();

    inFirstNotInSecond = file1Lines.Except(file2Lines);
    inSecondNotInFirst = file2Lines.Except(file1Lines);
}
```

The same is truth if you use `ReadAllLines`.

A *little* less performant solution, but much more memory efficient:

```
void GenerateDiff()
{
     inFirstNotInSecond = File.ReadLines(firstFile).Except(File.ReadLines(secondFile)).ToList();
     inSecondNotInFirst = File.ReadLines(secondFile).Except(File.ReadLines(firstFile)).ToList();
}
```

Since you are accessing same files they are likely to be cached, so drawback should be negligible.

P.S.: my answer is assuming *deferred execution* of [Except()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Deferred execution doesn't help here. Except needs access to *all* entries in one of the inputs in order to check whether a line from the other exists or not. In fact, the [source](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L785) shows that the second input is loaded first, then the first gets iterated. The only way to avoid loading one or the other input is to ensure they are sorted in advance

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, that means what only one file is *fully* loaded at any given time? Then that's not exactly what I thought, but still save a bit of memory (as the second file is simply iterated). Thanks.

Comment: it also means that the *second* file must be the smallest in order to get the best performance